# Can an app read iCal data on the iPHone/Pad in OS 3? OS 4?

Tags: iphone, icalendar

Pretty much the title: I'm interested in building an app that displays iCal calendar data.  But cant find a direct to to do it.  Am I missing something?   do the changes in OS 4 make this possible?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in 3.* version to access calendar lib in custom app, since calendar libraries are private. 
But in 4.0 you can access as it's documented.

> http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html

Answer (score 1):

While the EventKit in iOS 4 can definitely access the built-in calendar on an iDevice, it *can't* read a .ics file.  For that, I would recommend checking out [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/), a C library for reading and extracting data out of ics files.  It takes a little bit of effort to get it compiling for iPhone, but it's definitely possible.